# How to make an armor stand teleport in front of me no matter where I look?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make an armor stand teleport in front of me by like two blocks no matter where I look, but I couldn't get it to work. Can anybody help me out please? Also I am playing on Minecraft Java Edition, and the version is 1.20.4

Comment: Similar [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379875/how-to-teleport-player-5-blocks-in-front-of-them-with-command-blocks?rq=1), but you will have to switch the `<selector>` to your armor stand, and `@s` to `@p`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `^` symbol to teleport the armor stand relative to the player's body.

This command teleports the armor stand 2 blocks in the direction the player is looking:

```
execute at @p run tp @e[tag=tag] ^ ^ ^2
```

I added a second block after to set the y position of the armor stand to the same as the players:

```
execute as @p run data modify entity @e[tag=tag,limit=1] Pos[1] set from entity @s Pos[1]
```

---

I have an armor stand with the tag: `tag`, and I checked for the closest player. You can use any method to specify the player.

This will teleport the armor stand up to 2 blocks away, as it is 2 blocks away from the player's head in a straight line.

If you want something different edit your question or add a comment on my answer.